# How to iconify signal-desktop in the notification area

Tags: notifications

I try to minimize signal-desktop on linux and have an icon put in the notification area. Notifications are enabled in Preferences and I have set the line

```
Exec=/opt/Signal/signal-desktop --use-tray-icon --no-sandbox %U
```

But the icon does not turn up in the notification area and the messenger exits when I close the window.

Comment: Works with the latest update.

Answer (score 0):

I use:

```
kdocker -m -q -d 15 -i/home/dl3no/Bilder/Icons/Signal.png  /opt/Signal/signal-desktop --no-sandbox %U
```

in Autostart..